# lxc and google chrome cannot open display

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, lxc

I'm trying to run google chrome from an lxc container, but it fails despite my repeated attempts and various tweaks.

```
ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
CONTAINER=xenial-gui
CMD_LINE="google-chrome --disable-setuid-sandbox --user-data-dir $*"

STARTED=false

if ! lxc-wait -n $CONTAINER -s RUNNING -t 0; then
    lxc-start -n $CONTAINER -d
    lxc-wait -n $CONTAINER -s RUNNING
    STARTED=true
fi

PULSE_SOCKET=/home/ubuntu/.pulse_socket

lxc-attach --clear-env -n $CONTAINER -- sudo -u ubuntu -i \
    env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY PULSE_SERVER=$PULSE_SOCKET $CMD_LINE

if [ "$STARTED" = "true" ]; then
    lxc-stop -n $CONTAINER -t 10
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it works, when doing `xhost local:*` as root or with `sudo`. This command allows access to the screen for local users. I need to issue this, because I'm running unprivileged containers as different user as I log into my desktop.

If you are running a non privileged container, you could even further restrict this with `xhost local:username`. See also `man xhost`.

When I started to experiment, I accidently had this enabled and wondered a while after restarting my machine.